# Subgroup of semidirect product

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product

Let $G$ be a semidirect product of a normal subgroup $A$ with a subgroup $B$ and Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ such that $H\cap A$ is trivial. Is it true that $H$ is contained in a conjugate of $B$ ? How can I prove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas, it not true.

Possibly the simplest example is the dihedral group of order $8$,
$$
G = \langle a, b : a^4 = 1, b^2 = 1, b^{-1} a b = a^{-1} \rangle,
$$
with $A = \langle a \rangle$ and $B = \langle b \rangle$.

You can see that $H = \langle b a \rangle$, a subgroup of order $2$ which intersects $A$ trivially, is not conjugate to $B$.

This is because the centralizer of $b$ is $\langle b, a^{2} \rangle$, of order $4$. Thus $b$ has two conjugates, which are $b$ itself and $b^{a} = a^{-1} b a = b (b^{-1} a^{-1} b) a = b a^{2}$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I wonder if we can say: There is a subgroup $K$ of $G$ containing $H$ such that $G:=A \ltimes K$?

Comment: @SusanaOliveira, you're welcome. Will have to think about your question.

Comment: Arguably, the simple example for the original question is the Klein group, where every subgroup of order $2$ has two complements, and they are not conjugate.

Comment: A slightly more complicated example yields an example for the second question. Consider the abelian group $G=\langle a,b\mid a^2,b^4,[a,b]\rangle$. Let $A=\langle a\rangle$ and let $B=\langle b\rangle$. Clearly, $G$ is a (semi)direct product of A and B. Now, let $H=\langle ab^2\rangle$. This is a group of order $2$ and it intersects $A$ trivially, but all complements of $A$ are cyclic of order $4$ and $ab^2$ is not a square in $G$ so it will not be contained in any complement.

Comment: If you don't want the semidirect product to be direct, I'm guessing there is an example of order 16 of similar flavour as the above one.